# How do you turn a FileSet into a list of Files in a Mojo

Tags: java, maven-2

I'm writing my first Maven Mojo, in it I'm wanting to take a file set and process all the files it refers to.

In pseudo code what I'd like to do...

```
void myCode(org.apache.maven.model.FileSet fileSet) {
    List<java.io.File> files = FileSetTransformer.toFileList(fileSet);
    for (File f : files) {
        doSomething(f);
    }
}
```

So what I'm wanting is the real code for "FileSetTransformer.toFileList", it seems to me like a very common thing to want to do but I can't seem to find out how to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the javadoc for Maven [FileSet](http://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-model/apidocs/org/apache/maven/model/FileSet.html) and use the getDirectory() and getIncludes() methods. This is an example of an [existing maven mojo](http://code.google.com/p/birt-maven-plugin/source/browse/trunk/birt-maven-plugin/src/main/java/org/dailydev/mojo/birt/AbstractBirtMojo.java?r=20#227) that does something simular.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks emeraldjava, that gives me enough to work out the answer to my question.

plexus-utils has a utility class called FileUtils, you can add a dependency on it thus:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.codehaus.plexus</groupId>
  <artifactId>plexus-utils</artifactId>
  <version>1.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Once you have FileUtils you can implement the FileSetTransformer thus:

```
public final class FileSetTransformer {
        private FileSetTransformer () {
        }

        public static List<File> toFileList(FileSet fileSet) {
                File directory = new File(fileSet.getDirectory());
                String includes = toString(fileSet.getIncludes());
                String excludes = toString(fileSet.getExcludes());
                return FileUtils.getFiles(directory, includes, excludes);
        }

        private static String toString(List<String> strings) {
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                for (String string : strings) {
                        if (sb.length() > 0)
                                sb.append(", ");
                        sb.append(string);
                }
                return sb.toString();
        }
}
```